# Why spark varargs function countDistinct receive a single String/Column firstly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The declaration of `spark org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct` is:

```
def countDistinct(columnName: String, columnNames: String*): Column
def countDistinct(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): Column
```

The declaration receives variable arguments, but with a single String/Column firstly. So I cannot write code like this:

```
val id1sArr = id1.split(",").map(col(_))
df.agg(countDistinct(id1sArr: _*))
```

So my questions are:

1. Why varargs function `countDistinct` receive a single String/Column firstly?  What is the advantage and disadvantage of this type of declaration?
2. How to adapt this declaration if I want to pass variable arguments?

Comment: You can use `df.agg(countDistinct(id1sArr.head, id1sArr.tail : _*))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to why the declaration have a single string/column as the first argument is that
`countDistinct` **requires at least one argument**. If a declaration such as `countDistinct(columnNames: String*)` is used, zero arguments would be allowed.

As to how to pass a list of arguments, simply write:

```
df.agg(countDistinct(id1sArr.head, id1sArr.tail: _*))
```